# How to capture company name by regex statement in LibreOffice's Calc

Tags: regex, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

i'm using LibreOffice's Calc regex function to capture only company name from different strings.One Calc's cell consist of only one string. Those strings are structurized like this:

**C.H. Robinson o/Vienna** SZO13G9, SZO6P34, Roger Moor 
**Bus Trans Mouse** PT513AA, Anthony Hopkins
**P.H.U TRI-POL** ZMI14A8
**Mank** WXL89040, Jared Leto

Each string always starts with company name which apart from letters can include dot, number ofspaces(but not always), slash sign.
Name is followed by a car plate numer - which starts with capital letters(2+)folowed by digit(1+)followed by (but not always) with capital letter(0+) followed by(but not always) with digit(0+)

Sometimes after the comma there is second license plate, followed by (but not always) with name and surname.

Shortly -  i would like to capture part of the string from it's beginning to thefirst license plate numer not including space sign before it. I've marked the part i want to capture with bold font.

I tried this:
`/(.+)\s[A-Z]+[0-9]+[[A-Z]+]?[[0-9]+]?/gm`
but it's not working.

In many cases it's working, thanks @Hitesh, but there are still some cases that don't work: e.g.
 **ŁUKASZ MAZIAR** RDE66658, RDE0542P, Taras Stolbowski
 **MULTIBLOB** AR7238N, KR5P543, Jacek Stasiuk
 **Mir-Trans** WSI66671, WSI1671M, Stanisław Szymański
 **MIFESTA SPÓŁKA AKCYJNA** SJ1083T, WSI71321, STANISŁAW BOBROWSKI
 Sometimes the company name include polish letters. So far i dealed with them using `[\s\p{L}]+` but don't know how to use it in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Below pattern along with substitution will give you the exact result:

```
Pattern: (.*)\s[A-Z]{2,}[0-9]{2}.*
Substitution Group: $1
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/ESss6i/4

Where,

. Period -> matches a single character of any single character, except the end of a line.

[ ] Square brackets -> matches any single character from within the bracketed list

{n,}  -> Curly brackets with a number and a comma, matches minimum number of times the preceding character

Comment: @Bartek: Is this attempt helping you?

Comment: Just put those char under first parentheses with OR condition

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.
 Calc's regex function with empty 3rd param returns unmatched part, so i used `\s[A-Z]+[0-9]+.*` to select part of the string beginning from car's plate number onward, and regex function returned the rest.